# Static IP won't stick

Tags: networking, dhcp, static-ip

I'm having problems getting a static IP to work.  I'm running headless, so there is no Networking Manager (it has to be done via command line). Also, configuring a static IP thru the router is not an option for me as getting an address configured by a network administrator will take 2 weeks and I need to be able to configure the device from a list of approved IP's in 2 minutes.

I've assigned it in `/etc/network/interfaces` as follows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.4.123
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.4.0
    gateway 192.168.4.1
    broadcast 192.168.4.255
```

However, when I run `ifconfig` it continues to assign the address dynamically:

```
root@BBG1:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ec:24:b8:f6:d6:0b
          inet addr:192.168.4.26  Bcast:192.168.4.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ee24:b8ff:fef6:d60b/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2601:681:303:b10:ee24:b8ff:fef6:d60b/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST DYNAMIC  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4974 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:886 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:719167 (702.3 KiB)  TX bytes:93681 (91.4 KiB)
          Interrupt:175

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:1683 (1.6 KiB)  TX bytes:1683 (1.6 KiB)
```

I can get `ifconfig` to show the new IP if I run `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, but

1. the other IP remains active (I can continue to communicate with the device via SSH and ping the device using both IP's, simultaneously)
2. `ifconfig` continues to show `DYNAMIC`
3. when I reboot, it goes back to the dynamic IP of `192.168.4.26`

Can anyone see what I'm overlooking?

Comment: Did you disable network manager ? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic#Disable_network_managers_and.2For_wicd

Comment: Hmm odd, `auto eth0` & `allow-hotplug eth0` seem redundant try taking `allow-hotplug eth0` out

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Network Manager is already uninstalled, but thanks for the link to that page (excellent resource, bookmarked for future use).  @meccooll: I removed the `allow-hotplug eth0` line from `/etc/networking/interfaces`, ran `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, confirmed the IP changed in `ifconfig` (`DYNAMIC` is still there, right next to `MULTICAST`), rebooted the device, and it went back to the dynamic ip (`192.168.4.26`).  Apparently there's still something else controlling things.

Comment: Not sure. My guess is that either the ip address you are assigning is in use or your router is configured to disallow static IP

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I've been testing on my home network so I have control over the router.  I'm able to assign a static IP to my windows machine without any problems (even within the DHCP range of 192.168.4.2-100; I'm trying to use .123 on the device).  I've dialed my DHCP lease time back to 5 minutes so it's not forcing an old IP on the device.  Because it's a home router, there are only a dozen or so devices connected, so I went thru and double checked that nothing else is using that IP; currently the highest IP assigned is .19 (and yet the device continues to recieve .26...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  My system is utilizing ConnMan to manage the ethernet connection, so making changes to `/etc/network/interfaces` was being ignored.  In order to configure the interface, first I had to find the mac address of the interface, by typing `connmanctl services`.  I then used this command to configure the interface:

```
connmanctl config ethernet_<mac_address>_cable --ipv4 manual <ip_address> <netmask> <gateway> --nameservers <ip_address>
```

So in my case, it looked like this:

```
connmanctl config ethernet_ec24b8f6d60b_cable --ipv4 manual 192.168.4.123 255.255.255.0 192.168.4.1 --nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

This seems to be persisting thru reboots and holding the IP.